# using awk to average specified rows

Tags: shell, awk

I have a data file set up like

```
a   1
b   2
c   3 
d   4
a   5
b   6
c   7
d   6
etc
```

and I would like to output to a new file

```
a   average of 2nd column from all "a" rows
b   average of 2nd column from all "b" rows
etc
```

where a, b, c... are also numbers. 
I have been able to do this for specific values (1.4 in the example below) of the 1st column using `awk`:

```
awk '{  if ( $1 == 1.4) total += $2; count++ }
END {print total/10 }'  data
```

though `count` is not giving me the correct about of rows (i.e. count should be 10 as I have manually put in 10 to do the average in the last line).

I assume a for loop will be required but I have not been able to implement that correctly.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;c[$1]++}END{for(x in a)printf "average of %s is %.2f\n",x,a[x]/c[x]}'
```

the output of above line (with your example input) is:

```
average of a is 3.00
average of b is 4.00
average of c is 5.00
average of d is 5.00
```

Comment: Thanks, that does almost everything I want. However, the output is not in the same order (e.g. a, b, c, d... but instead b, d, a, c). Not sure why that is but is there a quick fix to put the order like the original?

Comment: `awk` is not good in sorting, so just add this after the `awk` command `| sort -k3`. It would sort the output using column number 3